# javascript a collection of buttons each submitting a different value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of buttons on a page, specifically, I have 10 rows and 5 columns, so 1st row i have 5 buttons, A1, B1, C1, D1, E1 ..., 2nd row i have A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, .. all the way until 10th row, A0, B0, C0, D0, E0.  Each of these button should have a value A1, A2, A3 etc when I submit. Is there anyway I can do this quickly, currently I have a javascript getElementById to get each of these buttons, but that is way too long. Imagine if I have to include more buttons. Is there any way I can loop these buttons to each have diffrent value and submit the value diffrently. I thought of using getElementsByClass, but that way I wouldnt know the index of each element anyway. Anyone has a more clever and programatic way to solve this? thanks.

Comment: yes using `forEach` function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp in jQuery it can be done using `each` function

Comment: Include the source code of your problem along with the thing you have tried. You can create plunker/fiddler snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scripting language for this. 
**THIS IS SAMPLE LOGIC:**
**IN PHP** (using for loop):

```
<?php 
  $letter='A';
  for($j=0; $j < 10; $j++) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {    
     if($i==0)
         $letter = 'A';
     else if($i==1)
         $letter = 'B';
     else if($i==2)
         $letter = 'C';
     else if($i==3)
         $letter = 'D';
     else if($i==4)
         $letter = 'E';
     else
         $letter = 'Z';               
?>
<input type = "button" id="<?php echo $letter . $j?>" value="<?php echo $letter . $j?>">
<?php } echo "<br />"; } ?>
```

This will generate the following output if written within the < body > tag:

```
<html>
<body>
                <input type = "button" id="A0" value="A0">
                <input type = "button" id="B0" value="B0">
                <input type = "button" id="C0" value="C0">
                <input type = "button" id="D0" value="D0">
                <input type = "button" id="E0" value="E0">
        <br />        <input type = "button" id="A1" value="A1">
                <input type = "button" id="B1" value="B1">
                <input type = "button" id="C1" value="C1">
                <input type = "button" id="D1" value="D1">
                <input type = "button" id="E1" value="E1">
        <br />        <input type = "button" id="A2" value="A2">
                <input type = "button" id="B2" value="B2">
                <input type = "button" id="C2" value="C2">
                <input type = "button" id="D2" value="D2">
                <input type = "button" id="E2" value="E2">
        <br />        <input type = "button" id="A3" value="A3">
                <input type = "button" id="B3" value="B3">
                <input type = "button" id="C3" value="C3">
                <input type = "button" id="D3" value="D3">
                <input type = "button" id="E3" value="E3">
        <br />        <input type = "button" id="A4" value="A4">
                <input type = "button" id="B4" value="B4">
                <input type = "button" id="C4" value="C4">
                <input type = "button" id="D4" value="D4">
                <input type = "button" id="E4" value="E4">
        <br />        <input type = "button" id="A5" value="A5">
                <input type = "button" id="B5" value="B5">
                <input type = "button" id="C5" value="C5">
                <input type = "button" id="D5" value="D5">
                <input type = "button" id="E5" value="E5">
        <br />        <input type = "button" id="A6" value="A6">
                <input type = "button" id="B6" value="B6">
                <input type = "button" id="C6" value="C6">
                <input type = "button" id="D6" value="D6">
                <input type = "button" id="E6" value="E6">
        <br />        <input type = "button" id="A7" value="A7">
                <input type = "button" id="B7" value="B7">
                <input type = "button" id="C7" value="C7">
                <input type = "button" id="D7" value="D7">
                <input type = "button" id="E7" value="E7">
        <br />        <input type = "button" id="A8" value="A8">
                <input type = "button" id="B8" value="B8">
                <input type = "button" id="C8" value="C8">
                <input type = "button" id="D8" value="D8">
                <input type = "button" id="E8" value="E8">
        <br />        <input type = "button" id="A9" value="A9">
                <input type = "button" id="B9" value="B9">
                <input type = "button" id="C9" value="C9">
                <input type = "button" id="D9" value="D9">
                <input type = "button" id="E9" value="E9">
        <br /></body>
</html>
```

You can apply the same logic in other scripting languages

Answer (score 0):

You can try with forEach, for, while, do while and etc.

Edited :

You can use each jquery. For example :

```
$('input[type=button]').each(function(i,e){
  $(this).val(whatever);
});
```

Comment: alright, I can try this. hmm, if I want to show a confirmation popup before it actually submits the value, how can I achieve that? So let say user press "A1",  I have a onclick check, which display 2 button, yes and no. Only if user press yes, I will submit the button value. How Can I achieve this correctly. because i dont know how to have the yes button to submit A1 button's value. thanks for the help

Comment: use prompt as mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**In jQuery:**

```
$.each ( collection, function ( key, value ) {

            console.log (key + " " + value);                            
});
```

[each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

**In JavaScript:**

```
  array.forEach(callback[, thisObject]);
```

[forEach()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_foreach.htm)

Answer (score 0):

if A1 is id = a1, B1 is id = b1,...

I hope this can help you

```html
var arr = ['A','B,'C','D','E'];
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
    var Code = arr[i]+String(j);
    $('#'+Code).on('click', function(){
      //anything you want
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];

const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

const form = document.getElementById('form');
const alphaInput = document.getElementById('alpha-input');

for (let i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');

  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    let input = document.createElement('input');

    input.type = 'button';
    input.value = i === 9 ? `${alpha[i]}0` : `${alpha[i]}${j + 1}`;

    input.addEventListener('click', () => {
      alphaInput.value = input.value;
    });

    div.appendChild(input);
  }

  frag.appendChild(div);
}

document.getElementById('button-container').appendChild(frag);

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (alphaInput.value) {
    console.log(`${alphaInput.value} was submitted`);
  } else {
    console.log('No button was clicked before you submitted this form');
  }

  alphaInput.value = '';
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div id="button-container"></div>
  <input type="hidden" id="alpha-input" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```